# Primeng table get currently displayed row count

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I am using primeng table and have enabled pagination for it.I'm trying to show the user the count of currently displayed records and the total records. Something like Showing 1-20 of 200 entries. However the issue with this is that if the records are not a multiple of 20, the last page reads showing 180 to 200 of 194 entries. I want it to be 180 to 194 of 194 entries. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my template

```
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft" let-state>
    <span>Showing {{(state.page * state.rows) + 1}} to {{state.rows * (state.page + 1)}} of {{state.totalRecords}} entries
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't just update condition?

```
(state.totalRecords > (state.rows * (state.page + 1))) ? state.rows * (state.page + 1) : state.totalRecords
```

In place of

```
 state.rows * (state.page + 1)
```